# mysql stored procedure that can take in multiple arguments

Tags: mysql

pretty new to mysql and just learned about stored procedures.
I was wondering if i can input multiple arguments when creating the procedure so that when i call the procedure i can put in any number of names and still have it work. here is an example of what i was working on.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployeeSalary(IN employee_last_name VARCHAR(16))
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS emp_sal;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE emp_sal
        (SELECT e.emp_no, e.last_name, s.salary
        FROM employees e 
        LEFT JOIN salaries s ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no);
    
    SELECT * FROM emp_sal;
        
    UPDATE emp_sal 
    SET salary = salary * 1.02
    WHERE last_name = employee_last_name;
    
    SELECT * FROM emp_sal;
END $$
DELIMITER;

CALL UpdateEmployeeSalary('Bamford');
```

the idea behind this one is whenever i call this function it shows 2 temporary tables. the 1st one is with the employee records with their salaries and the 2nd one is an updated version of the 1st table showing the increase in their salaries.

alternatively i created 2 procedures 1 for the original temp table and the 2nd one with the updated salary table. just wondering if i can put in multiple names as an argument instead of doing it one by one

Comment: Functions and Procedures are not the same thing - see manual or google sql functions vs procedure for differences and examples.

Comment: If you have a bunch of employees to update by name I suggest you create a temporary table containing them and join to that in your procedure.

Comment: Provide your "any number of names" as one solid value (for example, as CSV list or JSON array). In the procedure - parse this values list into temptable and use parsed separate values.